# DataFrame - Add a new ranking column

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, pandas-groupby

For the table below, consider just the first 2 columns 'Fruit' and 'percentage'.

How do you add a third column, ie. 'new_column' that looks at the 'Fruit' column in groups and
puts a number corrosponding to the percentage. For example, in the 'Apple' group - the highest percentage is 99 - so it is assigned 1....and so on.

So - given the 'Fruit' and 'percentage' column - how do you then add 'new_column' to the dataframe.

Hope this is clear and thankyou in advance.

| Fruit | percentage | new_column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 23 | 3 |
| Apple | 99 | 1 |
| Apple | 50 | 2 |
| Pear | 45 | 4 |
| Pear | 87 | 1 |
| Pear | 67 | 3 |
| Pear | 70 | 2 |
| Peach | 93 | 1 |
| Peach | 75 | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be like this:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Original data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
      'fruit': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Pear', 'Pear', 'Pear', 'Pear', 'Peach', 'Peach'], 
      'percentage': [23, 99, 50, 45, 87, 67, 70, 93, 75]
})
```

Output

[image]

Create new 'rank' column based on grouping the `df` dataframe on `fruit` and `rank` the value of `percentage` within the group.

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('fruit')['percentage'].rank()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That's great garagnoth - straight to the point. Much appreciated.